# Quartz: Job is not started when application starts

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz 2.2.3 and I have a job to be started 5mins after application started and then every day at 7 AM.
And my code is

```
          Trigger myTrigger =TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("myTrigger",Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP) 
                .startAt(new Date( inFiveMinutes ))
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(7,0)) 
                .forJob("myJob",Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP)
                .build();
```

The problem is, the job is not started in 5 mins but cron scheduler works. Interestingly startsAt works with SimpleScheduleBuilder. For example

```
SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMilliseconds(8L *60L *60L * 1000L).repeatForever()
```

I could create a pair of trigger and job to schedule one for every day and the other one is for 5min after startup.

Is there any better way of doing?

Comment: I have a similar requirement. I want my job to be started immediately when the application is started. I don't know how to do this. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check  the below code    

 Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()  
                .withIdentity("APICOUNTTRIGGER", "group1")
                .startAt(DateBuilder.todayAt(07, 00, 00))   
                .withSchedule(        
                        SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(24).repeatForever()) 
                .build();
```